# Not able to create a new record

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data

I have been trying to make this work for countless hours. I'm not able to find an answer that I can comprehend on the web. Other beginners like me may have the same issue that I have so I'm posting my question:

I'm having this error in my Ember app:
***Uncaught Error: Assertion Failed: You can only add a 'user' record to this relationship***

I'm trying to create a new record of "Cond". But I'm not able to add the 'user' object to the user attribute of the newly created Cond instance. However, from the Chrome debug tool, I can see that 'user' is not null or undefined. Here is the controller that crash:

```
    App.BookController = Ember.Controller.extend({
      needs: 'user',
      user: Ember.computed.alias("controllers.user"),

      frequency: ['Every Minute', 'Every Hour', 'Every Day', 'Every Week', 'Every Month', 'Every Quarter', 'Every Year', 'Continuous'],
      selectedFrequency: 'Every Month',

      actions: {
        createCond: function() {

          var user = this.get('user');

          var Cond = this.store.createRecord('Cond', {
            name: this.get('name'),
            frequency: this.get('selectedFrequency'),
            description: this.get('description'),
            createdDate: new Date(),
          });

          Cond.set('user', user);  // Application crash her
          user.addObject('Conds', Cond);

          Cond.save().then(function() {  
            user.save();
            console.log('new Cond created');
          });
        }
      }

    });
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your grabbing the user controller, the model is a property on the controller.

Either change the alias to:

```
user: Ember.computed.alias("controllers.user.model"),
```

or change your get to:

```
var user = this.get('user.model');
```

Comment: It is working great. Thanks Kingpin2k! For the benefit of other users, note that I had another error in my code: 'user.addObject('Conds', Cond);' should instead be: user.get('conds').pushObject(cond);